# passing $_GET associative array without [] in the URL (very short PHP question)

Tags: php, arrays, url

This must be a newbie question but...

How can I achieve $_GET['i'] array from URL "index.php?i=1&i=2&i3" instead of "index.php?i[]=1&i[]=2&i[]=3"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can not automatically transform `index?i=1&i=2&i=3` into an array variable. You will have to manually parse that and construct an array yourself.

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)=([^&]*)/', $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$_GET = array();
foreach ($match as $row) {
    list(, $key, $value) = $row;
    $_GET[$key][] = urldecode($value);
}
```

Note that this interfers with regular URL parameters. You will have to use a more sophisticated approach if you want to retain the normal behaviour.

Comment: I've never seen that notation before. Is not foreach($match as $key => $value)?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated because of the result structure that PREG_SET_ORDER will return. You have to manually unwrap the rows here.

Comment: Added `urldecode`. The regex is decidedly inexact in only accepting alphanumeric keys anyway, so need no decoding there.

Answer (score 2):

While the HTTP standard does not forbid that, PHP does not support it out-of-the-box. You have to do it yourself:

```
$q = 'a=1&a=2&a=3&b=1';

$vars = array();
foreach (explode('&', $q) as $part) {
    list($var, $value) = explode('=', $part, 2);
    $uvar = urldecode($var);
    if (isset($vars[$uvar])) {
        if (!is_array($vars[$uvar])) $vars[$uvar] = array($vars[$uvar]);
        $vars[$uvar][] = urldecode($value);
    } else {
        $vars[$uvar] = urldecode($value);
    }
}

print_r($vars);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [b] => 1
)
```

Just replace `$q` with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: Yes, true +1. The urldecoding is a good idea. But why would you prefer the `raw` variant? Should `+` signs work in url parameters?

Comment: @mario: Heh you're right, fixed that, thanks. I just have the habit of using `rawurlencode` so I used `rawurldecode` there without noticing. :)

Comment: The function name does make it sound more useful. You'll always have to peek at the manual to know what it really does.. ;} PHP nah